# How can I close a modally opened window with its own navigation stack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I have the following structure in my React Native project, suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660300/3151675):

```
export const Root = () => {
    const RootStack = useMemo(() => createStackNavigator(), []);
    const HomeStack = useMemo(() => createStackNavigator(), []);

    function renderHomeStack() {
        return (
            <HomeStack.Navigator>
                <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <HomeStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
            </HomeStack.Navigator>
        );
    }

    function renderRootStack() {
        return (
            <RootStack.Navigator>
                <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                <RootStack.Screen
                    name="HomeStack"
                    options={{
                        presentation: 'modal',
                    }}
                    component={renderHomeStack}
                />
            </RootStack.Navigator>
        );
    }

    return renderRootStack();
};
```

Currently, I want to go back from the Settings screen to the Login screen.

- I tried the solutions under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49804332/3151675), but they didn't work.
- I also tried using `DeviceEventEmitter` to send an event to the login screen to call navigation.popToTop() or navigation.goBack() - that didn't work either.

Comment: Simply you can navigate to the Login screen please try `navigation.navigate("Login")`

Comment: @YamanKATBY This doesn't work, as the navigation reference finds the inner stack and not the outer stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to pass the parent props before,

```
props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
```

or you can use AuthContext to save it in one location and goback,

```
      const initialLoginstate = {
        isLoading: true,
        userName: null,
        userToken: null,
      };

      const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
    
          case "LOGOUT":
            return {
              ...prevState,
              userName: null,
              userToken: null,
              isLoading: false,
            };
        }
      };

 
    const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        loginReducer,
        initialLoginstate
      );

 const authContext = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
    signOut: async () => {
    
                try {
                  await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userToken");
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log(e);
                }
                dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
        }),
        []
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Login' }],
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the navigation reference on the Settings screen doesn't know about the login screen. I need a way to access that other navigation reference somehow.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You just need to call `navigate` and pass in the id of the screen you want to navigate to.

i.e. The screen you want to see when the modal is closed:

```
props.navigation.navigate("MyScreen");
```

This will close the modal (as well as any of the screens that were in the modal).

**Option 2:**

```
props.navigation.popToTop();
props.navigation.goBack(null);
```